# NOT SURE WHAT IF FUNCTION CAN BE USE

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have this details, And I want my remarks to be automatically populated depends on what kind of PAPER I have.

**Example**

```
Column A - (Sales#) : 1234
Column B - (Warehouse) : FLOWER
Column C - (Purchase) : 001/5000123
Column D - (Paper) : "POD" or "GR"
Column E - (QTY) : 125
Column F - (Date) : 01/18/2020
Column G - (Remarks) : please help on the formula
```

For the Column D : I will be going to have either "POD" or "GR"
If Column D is "POD" my remarks would be like this.

> "POD shows COLUMN E cases good received dated COLUMN F shipped with COLUMN C"

morelike

> "POD shows 1215 cases good received dated 11/14/2019 shipped with 0106/5000541718"

But if "GR" my remarks would be like this.

> "Per AMS Solicitation – POD is optional, if GR is updated.
>   For mixed fruit orders, COLUMN B can opt to provide COL, see attached PO contract, instead"

morelike

> "Per AMS Solicitation – POD is optional, if GR is updated.
>   For mixed fruit orders, PLANT can opt to provide COL, see attached PO contract, instead"

THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 1):

Hows something like this?

```
=IFS(D2="POD",("POD shows "&E2&"  cases good received dated "&TEXT(F2,"mm/dd/yyyy")&" shipped with "&C2),D2="GR","Per AMS Solicitation – POD is optional, if GR is updated. For mixed fruit orders, "&B2&" can opt to provide COL, see attached PO contract, instead")
```

[image]